# In Firefox, is there any way for an extension to remove an entry from history?

Tags: javascript, firefox

In Firefox, I know that I can alter a page's History entry by using a content script to inject a call to history.replaceState. However, the page's address will still be visible in the history sidebar and offered as a suggestion in the awesome bar. Is there any way for an extension to remove these, too (as with chrome.history in the Chrome SDK?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [removePage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIBrowserHistory#removePage()) function of [nsIBrowserHistory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIBrowserHistory)